# SwiftUI no delay after specifying 2 seconds animation delay for view change

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, delay

Declared 2-seconds delay is not working.
"Hello, shopper!" text appears instantly after app's launch instead of image.
What I want is that image appears, stay 2 seconds on screen and then gently (with linear animation) change into text.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var launching = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if launching {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "AppIconImage")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            } else {
                Text("Hello, shopper!")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear.delay(2)) {
                launching = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot control *when* `onAppear` is called, so your expectation is rather wrong. Test instead this animation block in button action.

Comment: … and maybe you need to add a .transition() modifier, combined with a .animation(_, value:) modifier, depending on the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for Your comments. Fortunately, for now I managed to solve this just by adding app's launch screen. But it is possible that I will encounter this problem in the future.